# How to get data as JSON from a Sharepoint issuer tracker to display in FullCalendar JS

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, fullcalendar

Can someone please help me on how to get Sharepoint Issuer tracker list data as JSON data using (AJAX) so that i can use it in FullCalendar JS.

We have our Vacation Tracking done using Sharepoint Issuer tracker and we want to display approved request in the Calendar view (using FullCalendar JS).

We are currently using SP 2007.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In MOSS 2007 there is no official JSON support or libraried. You will have to write your own web service which can use the Server Object Model and read data from the issue tracker list.